# JS function is not defined (ReferenceError)

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this? I get an error that imText is not defined. I did some searching around and found that it has something to do with scope? Is there a better way of trying to achieve what I want to do because it also appears using the onClick event is not suggested either.

```
<script>
   function imText(text) {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font="20px Georgia";
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillText(text, 10, 50);
{
</script>

 <div class="canvas"></div>
  <canvas id="area"></canvas>
  <form action="text">
   <h2>Enter Text:</h2> 
   <input type="text" id="getText" name="text" value="bee"/><br>

   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="imText(document.getElementById('getText').value)" />
  </form>
```

Comment: The last char in your script (`{`) should be a `}`

Comment: You don't seem to be closing your `imText` function. It looks like a simple typo, replace the last `{` with `}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this closing bracket:

```
<script>
   function imText(text) {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font="20px Georgia";
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillText(text, 10, 50);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No big deal, a couple of mistakes: the closing bracket before `</script>` and the `getElementById` should reference "area" not "canvas", because you're giving the `canvas` element the id "area"

```
<script>
   function imText(text) {
    var c = document.getElementById("area");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font="20px Georgia";
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillText(text, 10, 50);
}
</script>

 <div class="canvas"></div>
  <canvas id="area"></canvas>
  <form action="text">
   <h2>Enter Text:</h2> 
   <input type="text" id="getText" name="text" value="bee"/><br>

   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="imText(document.getElementById('getText').value)" />
  </form>
```

Works in this [example link](https://jsfiddle.net/ffsyrpow/)

Comment: I added some extra css into the JFiddle link you provided so I can visualize it working, however it does not work. In the console of my browser it now says "TypeError: Cannot set property 'font' of null".

Comment: Not sure what browsers support those functions.. I'm on Chrome and it works fine. It may be your browser.

Comment: I am using chrome as well.